# How to draw Hasse diagram

Tags: relations

How would you draw a Hasse diagram of the divisibility relation?
when A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Write the element 1 at the bottom.  At one level above, write the primes $2,3,5,7,11,13$, and draw a line from each of them to the element 1.  At the second level above, write all elements that are a product of two primes, and draw a line from each of these elements to their prime factors. For eg, a line from 9 to 3, one from 6 to 3, one from 6 to 2, etc. Then lines from 12 to its factors 4, 6 in the level below it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

.....................................................

Comment: ohhhh i was in that direction, thanks @martin